# Can you do Regular Expressions in Excel without VBScript?

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex, worksheet-function

I'm looking for an Excel function that I can put in a cell to do a regex search of the contents of another cell.  Is there anything available to do this?  I'd prefer not to have to add VB Script to the spreadsheet for this because I can hard-code a solution faster.  It's just that the fastest solution would be a function.  I can't find one, though.  So maybe there's nothing.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 13):

You can simply add a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5' in the VBE to expose the VBScript.dll regex functions to Excel.  Writing a simple regex function is then trivial, e.g.

```vb
Public Function emailCheck(rawEmail As String) As Boolean
    Dim reg As New RegExp
    reg.Pattern = "^[\w-\.]{1,}\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,4}$"
    emailCheck = False
    If reg.Test(rawEmail) Then
        emailCheck = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Can you explain how you add a reference?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Looks like the answer is to open up Visual Basic inside Excel using Alt + F11. Then click Tools -> References, scroll down to his exact quote, and add it in. Then `RegExp` shows up when you type it.

Comment: So it turns out that you can actually use `Dim reg As Object` and then `Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")` instead of `Dim reg As New RegExp` and having to manually add the reference.

Answer (score 8):

The .xla package at [this site](http://blog.malcolmp.com/2010/regular-expressions-excel-add-in) worked very well for me.

Comment: It works great indeed (I'm using Excel 2013)

Answer (score 3):

[MoreFunc.xll](http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english/index.htm) is a free addin that has Regex functionality.

There are some other third-party addins that can do Regex also.

There are no true native worksheet functions to do it, but if you have a specific search to do you can probably use other functions to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I found that library, but we were hoping to have something that didn't require us to distribute a library, too.

Comment: @Erick, yep, I hate adding addins to my spreadsheets, a big pain to keep track of them.  Unless you need complete regex flexibility, you can probably get the job done with other functions.  There's a lot of tricks in Excel.  Post specific requests here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that gives the number of regular expression matches within a particular cell:

```
Public Function regexCount(regex As String, ref As Range) As Integer
    Dim reg As New RegExp
    reg.Global = True
    reg.Pattern = regex
    regexCount = reg.Execute(ref.Value).Count
End Function
```

(Requires adding a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5' - just go to 'Tools' --> 'References' from the VBA editor and check the checkbox for that reference.)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I did a regex replace to extract the number(s) from a cell:

```
Function REGREP(value As Range, searchString As String, replaceString As String,
  Optional ignoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional searchGlobal As Boolean = True)
  'Dim reg As New RegExp
  Dim reg As Object
  Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  reg.ignoreCase = ignoreCase
  reg.Global = searchGlobal
  reg.Pattern = searchString
  REGREP = reg.replace(value.value, replaceString)
End Function
Function ASNUM(value As Range)
  ASNUM = REGREP(value, "[^0-9.]+", "")
End Function

'Usage:
REGREP(A1, "[^0-9.]+", "")
ASNUM(A1)
```

**Note** that you first need to open up Visual Basic inside Excel using `Alt + F11`. <s>Then click `Tools -> References`, scroll down to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`, and add it in. Then `RegExp` shows up when you type it.</s>

**You need to save the file as an Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), in order to keep the macro...** You can also export and import your code Module.

Comment: Please note that the title of the question sid "without VBScript".

Comment: @AndrewMorton While that is true, the answer is it is not possible. Therefore, this is the best possible alternative, as it lets you as easily as possible add a regex function to your Excel spreadsheet. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Ah, I see you're a "programmer for many years in mostly VB.NET". Extra thanks then!