# How to do concise two alternative substitutions in Windows Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you do Regular Expressions in Excel without VBScript?](https://superuser.com/questions/181005/can-you-do-regular-expressions-in-excel-without-vbscript)

I wish to replace a string pattern with another along the lines of the following:

> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(name," Vlue", " Replace")," Value", " Replace")

Wherein I am looking for either " Value" or " Vlue" and replacing it with " Replace".

Perhaps something heading in this direction (that does not work):

> =SUBSTITUTE(name," V?lue", " Replace")

How can I easily achieve this in Excel 2010 on Windows?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically, or just using manual Search and Replace?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Programmatically in an Excel cell.  Thus far it is just using `substitute` and trying both cases, but I imagine there is a better way.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Va?lue` to match what you're describing?

Comment: Except that doesn't `?` require one character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that easy as you expect it to be.

First of, `?` requires a letter, hence is not suited for your case, because only 5 letter words would be accepted, not *Vlue*.

To do this replacement with formulas I needed the following:

```
A1 = "this is vlue test"
B1 = "v*lue"
```

Position, where *v*lue* begins

```
C1 = SEARCH(B1,A1,1)
```

Position, where *v*lue* ends. This might need improvement.

```
D1 = SEARCH(" ",A1,C1)
```

Substitution:

```
E1 = SUBSTITUDE(A1,MID(A1,C1,D1-C1),"REPLACE")
```

You can of course combine this all into one formula, but because it will get quickly confusing, I didn't.