# How to replace partial text in cell with partial text from another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How do you take (A1) 123456xxxx and pull out the last four digits from another cell such as (A2) 887890, grabbing just the 7890  - result of 1234567890, or even better, 123-456-7890?

Comment: have you tried using a regular expression - http://superuser.com/questions/181005/can-you-do-regular-expressions-in-excel-without-vbscript

Answer (score 2):

> =LEFT(A1,3)&"-"&MID(A1,4,3)&"-"&RIGHT(A2,4)

For further information on how any of the three Excel functions LEFT, RIGHT and MID work, have a read of [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/save-time-by-using-excels-left-right-and-mid-string-functions/1033367).

Comment: Where does this formula go? We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution and how to implement it.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was obvious given the Excel context. This is a formula which can go in any cell to give you the output requested. For further information on how any of the three Excel functions LEFT, RIGHT and MID work, have a read of this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/save-time-by-using-excels-left-right-and-mid-string-functions/1033367

Comment: No reason to be sorry. I am just trying to help you give more complete answers. It is a good idea not to assume anything. Think about the people who will read this a question; will readers understand how to apply your answer?