# How to Replace Words With VBScript Regex and VBA?

Tags: vba, regex, vbscript

what is vbscript syntax for .net:

```
\b[a-z]+\b
```

Hi

trying to replace all alpha words in the source.

.net regex tester confirms this pattern will find all words:

```
\b[a-z]+\b
```

this:

> Findings,Actions

returns:

> Findings
>
> Actions

http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

But, in excel vba with vbscript object, it fails:

```
Sub test()
    Dim re As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    re.Global = True
    re.Pattern = "\b[a-z]+\b"
    Debug.Print re.Replace("Findings, Actions", "xyz")
    Set re = Nothing
End Sub
```

' output is same as input-- no replace happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub test()

    Dim RE As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    RE.ignoreCase = True
    RE.Global = True

    RE.Pattern = "\b[a-z]+\b"
    Debug.Print RE.Replace("Findings,Actions", "xyz")

End Sub
```

#### Output

> xyz,xyz

Comment: Oops! Just needed ignoreCase. Glad to see my code was otherwise correct! -thx

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did a regex replace to extract the number(s) from a cell:

```
Function REGREP(value As Range, searchString As String, replaceString As String,
  Optional ignoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional searchGlobal As Boolean = True)
  'Dim reg As New RegExp
  Dim reg As Object
  Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  reg.ignoreCase = ignoreCase
  reg.Global = searchGlobal
  reg.Pattern = searchString
  REGREP = reg.replace(value.value, replaceString)
End Function
Function ASNUM(value As Range)
  ASNUM = REGREP(value, "[^0-9.]+", "")
End Function

'Usage:
REGREP(A1, "[^0-9.]+", "")
ASNUM(A1)
```

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/a/183409/439537

Comment: And: https://superuser.com/a/1787146/439537