# Field equals regular expression

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my excel file, I'd like field `A2` to equals regular expression match of field `A1`. The regular expression is as follows: `^NATURE-[0-9]+` .

Intuitively, the formula for A2 would be:

`=RegEx(A1,"^NATURE-[0-9]+")`

Except there's no Regex function. How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you do Regular Expressions in Excel without VBScript?](http://superuser.com/questions/181005/can-you-do-regular-expressions-in-excel-without-vbscript)

Comment: could be but I don't know how to write Visual Basic functions